# Filtering column value based on unique value, but not repeated for different value of the same column on the same unique value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

Looking for ways to filter unique values with `inactive` status, but not repeated as `active` status under the same unique value.

df:

```
Unique_value    Status
1               Active        <- Has both active and inactive, must be inactive only
1               Active        <- Has both active and inactive, must be inactive only
1               Inactive      <- Has both active and inactive, must be inactive only
1               Inactive      <- Has both active and inactive, must be inactive only
2               Inactive      <- Has inactive only
2               Inactive      <- Has inactive only
2               Inactive      <- Has inactive only
3               Inactive      <- Has inactive only (cancelled okay to be filtered out)
3               Cancelled     <- Has inactive only (cancelled okay to be filtered out)
3               Inactive      <- Has inactive only (cancelled okay to be filtered out)
```

Desired output:

```
Unique_value    status
2               Inactive
3               Inactive
```

What I tried so far, but I don't think this is correct.

```
p = ['Inactive', 'Active']
df.groupby('Unique_value')['Status'].apply(lambda x: (x =='Inactive') != set(p))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if `any` of the values in each group are `Active` or `Inactive`. Then get rid of the groups where both conditions are true:

```py
m1 = df["Status"].eq("Active").groupby(df["Unique_value"]).transform("any")
m2 = df["Status"].eq("Inactive").groupby(df["Unique_value"]).transform("any")
df[~(m1 & m2)].groupby("Unique_value", as_index=False).first()
```

```
   Unique_value    Status
0             2  Inactive
1             3  Inactive
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets try

```
g=df[df.groupby('Unique_value')['Status'].transform(lambda x: ~(x.eq('Active').any()))]

g[g['Status'].eq('Inactive')].drop_duplicates()
```